# How to restart a function through that same function?

Tags: python, function, class

How can I restart a function through itself? Here is what the function is:

```
class thingamajig():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def dostuff(self):
        number = random.randint(0, 3)
        if number == 3:
            #restart here??????
thing = thingamajig()
thing.dostuff()
```

How can I restart the function?

Comment: `while` loop if the value isn't `n` ?

Comment: While loop, but you probably shouldn't be fetching user input from *within* a class method. Instead you should be providing user input *to* the class method.

Comment: What is the issue? Do you want to limit how many times it can restart or something?

Comment: What do you mean by _"this doesn't seem to work"_? What is it supposed to do? It does not look like it does anything.

Comment: here is what i'm going to do: i'm going to edit the question, then answer it myself. Sorry, I just figured out what is wrong with my code, and it has nothing to do with this question. I am going to edit it, then answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a while loop in dostuff, for example:

```
def dostuff(self):
    whatever you need the code to do
    doagain = input('Want to do this again? y/n ')
    while doagain != 'n':
        whatever you need the code to do
        doagain = input('Want to do this again? y/n ')
```

Note that this problem of having to restate the code is solved using a do/while loop in C++, but this will do for Python

Comment: FYI you can write a do/while loop in Python beginning `while True:` and breaking on the relevant condition ([example](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-emulate-a-do-while-loop-in-python)). That eliminates the need to repeat `whatever you need the code to do` and the call to `input()`.

Answer (score -1):

How About:

```
class thingamajig():
    def __init__(self):
      pass
    def dostuff(self):
        doagain = input('Want to do this again? y/n ')
        if doagain == 'y':
            self.dostuff()
thing = thingamajig()
thing.dostuff()
```

Comment: Will work, up to a point, but then fail with RecursionError. Recursion is almost never the solution to this type of problem; loop iteration is.

Comment: Well... I think That's What codecrafter_123 wants?

Answer (score -1):

This is how you do it:

```
class thingamajig():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def dostuff(self):
        number = random.randint(0, 3)
        if number == 3:
            self.dostuff()
thing = thingamajig()
thing.dostuff()
```

The class only knows its parameters, and its own variables. Self is a keyword that will say "this class".

Comment: This is one way to do it, and it's a very bad way. You are introducing problems when you don't need to. The loop equivalent is trivially simple to write and is much better in every respect.

Comment: I couldn't delete the question, so what should I do?

Comment: The question is fine. Do you mean delete the original question, or delete this answer?

Comment: The whole question.